# PCB software available for gnome

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation

I'm looking for PCB software in Ubuntu. Ideally I want to design a circuit without needing it to be really specific. I cannot seem to find any software available. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Eagle** is a good tool for schematics entry and PCB layout, as mentioned before. It is cross platform and works under Linux, Mac OS X and Windows.

However, if you use the `apt-get install` method, the version might not be the latest and greatest. For example, Ubuntu 12.04 repositories currently host Eagle version **5.12.0**, while the latest available version for download is **6.5.0**.

This is how to get the latest version:

Go to [cadcoftusa download website here](https://www.cadsoftusa.com/download-eagle/) and download the latest version for Linux, for example this file:

```
wget ftp://ftp.cadsoft.de/eagle/program/6.5/eagle-lin-6.5.0.run
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x eagle-lin-6.5.0.run
```

Then run the installer:

```
./eagle-lin-6.5.0.run
```

and answer all the questions as needed, for example, the directory where you want it installed. Should you want to place it in the /opt/ or other global location, you may need to prepend the installation program with `sudo`

Also, you can change the license options later.

Answer (score 8):

**Eagle**

> Eagle includes a layout editor, schematic editor and autorouter.

To install Eagle

```
sudo apt-get install eagle
```

---

**PCB designer**

> This one seems to be more complex than eagle with better(complex) features like rats nest feature, design rule checking and industry standard RS-274-X(gerber)

To install PCB designer

```
sudo apt-get install pcb-gtk             #maybe pcb-lesstif too
```

---

**gEDA Schematic**

> This one is intended to be user friendly and easy to use, similar to Eagle.

To install gEdA Schematic.

```
sudo apt-get install geda
```

---

**Kicad**

> This one seems to be overconfident.No info, No screenshot.But it's a PCB designer and comments/ratings are good.

To install Kicad

```
sudo apt-get install kicad
```

---

**Fritzing**

> In it's Beta, this may not be one you would want to use professionally.But it's worth giving a try.Worth noting that it has something like **Autocompletion**.

To install Fritzing

```
sudo apt-get install fritzing
```

---

***Some helpers to above***

- Gerbv gerber file viewer
- Electric
- Visolate

---

Personally, *I think Eagle would best suit your needs*.All of the above are Open source and free, just to mention.

Comment: @elomage Thanks.If you know any PPA for any of the above software which provides latest versions, do share it.

Comment: Eagle installs easy without PPA (I don't know any). OK, wait, I'll add an answer showing how to install.

Comment: Do you have a source for Eagle being open source? From what I know, in general it's closed-source, non-free with crippled free version available.

Answer (score 3):

- gEDA Project (with `pcb` and `gerbv` tools)
- KiCad
- Fritzing

All are in Ubuntu repository.

See http://www.gpleda.org/

Answer (score 1):

Eagle is a commercial closed-source product.  There is a limited capability free (non-commercial use) version available, though for any non-trivial project that isn't enough.  (One schematic page and 4x6 inch 2-sided PCB doesn't get you all that far.)

That said, it *is* quite a good product, if you can live within the limitations of the free version, or are willing to pay for the less limited commercial licenses.  Among other things, defining new devices (schematic symbols and PCB footprints) is straightforward, which isn't necessarily true for other programs including some very expensive "professional" ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think EasyEDA will meet your need. [EasyEDA](https://easyeda.com) is a free Web-based EDA tool which provides schematic capture, simulation and PCB design.
It’s a perfect tool for helping you complete your design from schematic to the finished PCB in the shortest time and easiest way. No matter you are using Mac, Linux or Windows; Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera, or Safari, EasyEDA has all the features you expect and need to rapidly and easily take your design from conception through to production.

EasyEDA aims to bring an easier EDA experience to every electronic hobbyist. \There is a large amount of open projects on it. Users can access to Open Source modules developed by thousands of electronics engineers. https://easyeda.com/explore